# JAVA UDF Timeout

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running the brand new Java UDF in my Snowflake env ( Azure ) for text analysis using CoreNLP. I'm getting the below error for just 100 records. It succeeds for 10 records.

Handler execution timed out in 13.782877666s vs. max of 5s in function INSTRUCTION_ANALYZER with handler com.nlp.InstructionAnalyzer.getNamedEntity

Is there a workaround for this ? Can I set the timeout somewhere or is it a limitation of Java UDF.

Comment: I suggest you open a support case as Java UDFs are still in preview and you'll likely be able to get some good attention on this.

Comment: Can you share more about what you're doing such that processing a single row takes 13 seconds?

Comment: The 5 seconds limit is for each record, so more records does not necessary trigger the limit, but rather the other 90 records might have one or few in them that is taking a long time. You might want to narrow down to that record and see what's inside. In my experience, a few types of contents are really slow
1. Content containing CJKV characters (Chinese, Japanese, Korean and Vietnamese)
2. Content has a lot of HTML tags like
`<html><head></head><body><div>`
3. Content that has no newline, but just a giant one-liner instead.